# Concurrently grabbing jobs from rethinkdb

Tags: concurrency, rethinkdb

I've been playing with rethinkdb lately and tried to implement a job queue. I just wonder what is the best technique to, concurrently, grab jobs from a table?

The threads are not many and jobs take a bit of time to run, so it would be ok to e.g. make an updated failed if a given value is present. E.g if two concurrent processes grab a job and tries to set a workerId, the second competing process would fail and just retry.

So I wonder how to do this in rethinkdb? My current approach is a bit of a hack, where the second process overwrite the first process workerId, and reset it, if it notices that the old_val wasn't null. I would rather that the second process just fails...or some other solution that makes rethinkdb handle this (if possible, only with rethinkdb and not a MQ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can atomically update and retrieve a document in a single query. For example, in JavaScript:

```
 r.table('foo').filter({status: 'pending'}).limit(1).update(
   r.branch(r.row('status').eq('pending'), {status: 'in progress'}, {}),
   {returnChanges: true})
```

That query finds a document that has a status of `'pending'`, changes the status to `'in progress'` and returns the document.

Comment: Ah r.branch. Excellent. Will try this out. ty!